# Python-Spyder IDE Freezing

Tags: python, spyder

I recently started using python after switching from MATLAB. To date the best IDE that I have found to use is Spyder but I keep having one problem with it. Once in a while when I open it, it will freeze the whole PC and I will have to switch off the PC and turn it on to use it again. Has anyone else had this problem and know how to fix it? I know everyone says PyCharm is the way to go but it feels considerably worse to me tbh

Comment: Python version? Spyder version?  How did you install Spyder?

Comment: Python version 3.4 and I installed Spyder through Anaconda, pretty sure it is Spyder version 2???

Comment: @Lererferler do you still have the same issue or this question is not relevant anymore?

Comment: I used Spyder for several months, and I ran into a lot of bugs like this one. A much better IDE for python is intelligent PyCharm. The "community edition" costs no money, and is 10 times better than Spyder in my opinion.